# Is there a way to get the type of something thrown?

Tags: c++, exception, boost-python

I have a code calling some Python from C++ (with Boost.Python). I have an exception thrown when trying to get the error from Python. But my question is quite general :

If the execution throws something in a `try` scope, is there a way to determine the type?

Example where I try all the possible kind of exceptions I know, without success :

```
try { instruction(); }
catch(my_own_namespace::Exception const& e) { /*...*/ }
catch(std::exception const& e) { /*...*/ }
catch(std::string const& s) { /*...*/ }
catch(char const* s) { /*...*/ }
catch(...) { /* I'm here, and I want information about what is thrown */ }
```

Comment: Simple solution: Only throw exception objects based on `std::exception`?

Comment: This is why it is recommended to have all exceptions deriving from `std::exception` so that you always have a `what()` method by design to give you information (and potentially one catch clause to rule them all :D ). To my knowledge, if you enter a `catch(...)` the only thing you can infer is that the thrown exception was none of the previous catched types.

Comment: You have to read the doc of `instruction()` in hope it tells the types of possible exceptions.

Comment: @Jarod42 :  Actually, `instruction()` is an obscure block of code calling Python and boost::python routines in order to analyse the traceback from python after a previous throw of `boost::python::error_already_set`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yeah, but I don't have this control on libraries...

Comment: If you leave out the wildcard clause, does the "uncaught exception" message say anything?

Comment: `my_own_namespace::Exception` should be derived from `std::exception`. Anything that throws `std::string`, `char const *`, or (and I have seen this happen...) `int` should be brought out around the back, thoroughly beaten, and then put in the trash compactor.

Comment: @DevSolar : I don't plan to trash Python lib... Sorry...

Comment: Big names don't safeguard from terrible design decisions.

Comment: @molbdnilo I can't let the error go to the OS, the code is quite complex. I finally found it's a `boost::python::error_already_set` thrown when I try to analyse another captured `boost::python::error_already_set` (no function `what()` provided to understand why). The general question remains interesting.

Comment: @Caduchon: His suggestion was that you let it leak to the OS **once in test** and see if the "uncaught exception" message will tell you **the programmer** what the type is. Once you see that, then you can add that type to your `catch` block.

Comment: @MooingDuck : I well understood. But this code is used in a lot of noexcept functions, including destructors (then I have to capture everything).

Comment: You don't actually. Even in noexcept and even in constructors, you can just let the exception leak, and most implementations of C++ will tell you the exception class name.

Comment: @MooingDuck you're write. I tried with a dummy test : `terminate called after throwing an instance blahblahblah`. Then it looks like a dev solution.